# Typescript file import with relative path failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Trying to run `src/index.js` I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './utils/spinner'
```

`index.js` import looks like this:

```js
const { startSpinner, stopSpinner } = require('./utils/spinner')
```

Folder structure:

[image: fold_struc]

`tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```js
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/__tests__/*",
    "src/**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

`@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 12",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2019", "es2020.promise", "es2020.bigint", "es2020.string"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

I have tried adding `baseUrl` to `tsconfig.json` and set it to `.src` , `src`, `/src` and tried to the same with every variation for `rootDir`.

Comment: You cannot import a TypeScript file from a JavaScript file

Comment: Change `index.js` to `index.ts` and run the whole thing with `ts-node`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Comment: @BennoGrimm that worked! I think the previous owner of the project must have been running it this way. If you reply again with this as the answer, I'd be glad to accept it. PS I didn't even have to change index.js to index.ts. Just running it with ts-node worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by renaming `index.js` to `index.ts` and running the whole thing with `ts-node`: https://npmjs.com/package/ts-node.